# Is there really a Bug in ls -l not observing the Environment Variable TIME_STYLE?

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

Look at this: I want to let `ls- l` **always show the date formatted as long-iso**. I was told to add a file `/etc/profile.local` with the line `export TIME_STYLE=long-iso`. I did so, as shown below under `#1`.

However, there is no environment variable `TIME_STYLE` as shown in `#2`.

`#3` shows the version of the `ls` command (this all happens with Xubuntu 16.04 LTS).

As shown in the output of `#4`, `ls` does not format the date part as `long-iso`.

Ok, if it is just because the environment variable `TIME_STYLE` is missing (**why?**), then I set it in `#5` and, as a proof that it exists, I echo it in `#6`.

Despite of that, `ls -l` in `#7` does not honour that!

Of course, if I explicitly require the date format as `long iso` as shown in `#8`, the date is formatted that way. But I want to let `ls -l` always show the date as `long-iso` without having to tell it on every invocation and I also want to avoid to create an alias for `ls -l` which incorporates this parameter (which of course would be easy to do, but that's not sportsmanlike).

**What's wrong here?** Some basic misunderstanding? Or is it really a bug? I can't really believe it **in ls -l**!

```
a@v:~$ cat /etc/profile.local                 # 1
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
a@v:~$ echo "${TIME_STYLE}"                   # 2

a@v:~$ ls --version                           # 3
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.25
...
a@v:~$ ls -l /etc/profile.local               # 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27 Dez 30 19:18 /etc/profile.local
a@v:~$ TIME_STYLE=long-iso                    # 5
a@v:~$ echo "${TIME_STYLE}"                   # 6
long-iso
a@v:~$ ls -l /etc/profile.local               # 7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27 Dez 30 19:18 /etc/profile.local
a@v:~$ ls -l --time-style="${TIME_STYLE}" /etc/profile.local  # 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27 2018-12-30 19:18 /etc/profile.local
a@v:~$
```

Edit: As dessert taught us: After using sudo nano to append a line `export TIME_STYLE=long-iso` to the existing file `/etc/bash.bashrc` I got:

`a@v:~$ ls -l /etc/bash.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2374 2019-01-02 00:23 /etc/bash.bashrc
a@v:~$`

Thank you, dessert, for your help and especially for your explanations why `ls -l` did not work as intended.

Comment: You forgot to export the variable, `TIME_STYLE=long-iso ls -l` as well as `export TIME_STYLE=long-iso; ls -l` both work as expected.

Comment: `/etc/profile.local` is not recognized by `bash`, see [`man bash`/INVOCATION](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#invocation). Add the `export` line to either `/etc/bash.bashrc` or preferably your `~/.bashrc` and it will be read by every new `bash` interactive shell.

Comment: You need to export the variable because `ls` is an external program rather than a shell builtin.